# How would you design this database? Individual and group ownership

Tags: mysql, database

I have a list of items, and items can be owned either by an individual person or a group of people.

So far I have 3 tables like:

**People:**

```
personID  (primarykey)
personName
personAddress
...
```

**Groups:**

```
groupID  (primarykey)
groupNumber
personID
```

**Items:**

```
itemID  (primarykey)
itemName
itemDescription
itemWeight
...
```

How would you go about assigning ownership of items to an individual, or a specific group?

I did have 2 fields on the item, `owner_personID` and `owner_groupID`, but seems kinda janky, and have to manually manage which field to use at a time.

I also tried two linking tables, `PeopleOwnerships`, and `GroupOwnerships`, that store a list of items owned. With fields like, `personID/groupID` and `itemID`. But, seems even more jankier and can get messy. Have to be extra careful so that both individuals and groups don't own the same item at the same time.

I have also thought about putting all individuals in their own individual group, and just using the Groups table to refer to everything. But that also seems kind of weird.

I would also need to record the transfer of items, between people and groups, when ownership changes. I've thought about having a date field in the linking tables, and using the highest date to determine who owns what.

Answer (score 0):

You could treat a person as a group of 1 person, and only allow groups to own items.

Something better may be to have a class called "Owner" which only has the ID of the item and its ID (the id of the owner), and get both classes Person and Group extending it.

About the transfers, I wouldn't rely that business logic on the database.